# Is there a theorem in real analysis that relates the interval of continuity of a function to the interval of continuity of its derivative?

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a theorem in real analysis that relates the interval of continuity of a function to the interval of continuity of its derivative? So for example, in complex analysis, we are given a theorem that if a complex function is analytic in a domain, it is infinitely differentiable and analytic in the same domain. Does real analysis have a similar theorem or lemma?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not. For instance, the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) is a concrete example of a continuous everywhere but differentiable nowhere. By integrating it however many times you like, you get a function which is $n$-fold differentiable everywhere but nowhere $(n+1)$-fold differentiable.

Note that there's some mismatch between the question asked and the result from complex analysis cited. We can whip up a complex version of the Weierstrass function to demonstrate that in complex analysis there is also no way to deduce differentiability from continuity. However, what we *can't* do is the more "iterative" construction above: holomorphicity/analyticity in complex analysis is a **vastly** more powerful property than differentiability in real analysis.